# Fixed typo in C code, still won't build

Tags: android, android-ndk, compiler-errors

I am converting someones Palm Pilot code into an Android application for them. This involves me using the NDK to read from one of their already built libraries. For this, I need to create several new functions.

```
void __stdcall FreeRelay(void){
    RelayAPI_DataValid=0;
    RelayAPI_SetBaud=0;
    RelayAPI_get=0;
    RelayAPI_put=0;
    RelayAPI_flush=0;
    RelayAPI_delay=0;
    RelayAPI_initilized=0;
}

void Java_my_MainMenu_FreeRelayJava( JNIEnv * env, jobject this ) {
    RelayAPI_DataValid = 0;
    RelayAPI_SetBaud = 0;
    RelayAPI_get = 0;
    RelayAPI_put = 0;
    RelayAPI_flush = 0;
    RelayAPI_delay = 0;
    RelayAPI_initilized = 0;
}
```

Now, my error is in the last line of the second method. I had originall had it spelled `RelayAPI_initialized`, I know that thats correct, but I'm not going through the trouble of changing all of this C code for the typo. I'll make my function fit with the old code. Anyway, I tried `ndk-build` and got this.

[image]

Now in between those separate `ndk-build` calls, I fixed the error. But it still is telling me in line 615 there is an error dealing with `RelayAPI_initialized` but its NOT THERE. I don't know whats going on, and I really know very little about C. I saved my files with the updated information then called `ndk-build`. WHAT AM I MISSING?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a clean of your build. so the party built stuff is deleted and you get a full rebuild.

Comment: I've done this to no avail. What order should I do this in to make sure I'm doing it correctly. ndk-build clean, then just ndk-build should work?

Comment: where is relayapi_initialized declared? i cant see any declarations for those variables.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm asking. `RelayAPI_initilized` has been declared and is already used in multiple other functions. I wrote my own variable `RelayAPI_initialized` so it gave me the above error. I went back and fixed the spelling to match the member that is already everywhere throughout the code, and it is literally giving me the EXACT same error. Telling me in the line that I'm looking at its still spelled `RelayAPI_initialized` even though it is not.

Comment: I see.did you  press save? check with notepad that the file you are compiling has been updated. make a clean and then look through the directories to check that .o files are gone and other non-source files.

Comment: Well, I closed the program and re-opened the file afterwards and it is updated the way I want it to be. I have looked in the JNI folder but cannot find any .o files. I know nothing of how to work C, are they located somewhere else?

Comment: look at the error message, it tells you where the .o files are.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14695/discussion-between-juice-and-markus-mikkolainen)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can grep to find if other var like RelayAPI_* are defined GLOBALLY in some c code or header file.
if not, define it, or don't set it.

it will resolve compilation error... but probably it wont work